# MySQL maximum Connection

Tags: mysql

I have set the value of max_connection to 32 for a MySQL Master server. If I attach 5 MySQL slaves to this master then How many more connection shall be establish with this MASTER. Is Slave connection to Master is counted in max connection value.?

Answer (score 1):

Slave connections are just like any other connection.  They are counted against max_connections.

Of course, slaves can cascade to essentially an infinite depth, so slaves A and B could connect to the master, C could connect to A, then D to B, then E to D, etc.  Only the slaves that connect *directly* to the master would count as connections on the master.

Note that 32 connections is a *really* small number.  It would be pretty rare that this would be a useful value.